# How to use C socket API to connect to server on my own computer?

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I have a C program which sends the name of a file to a server. That server sends a file back to the program, which saves that file onto the disk. I want to test my program and try to transfer a file.

This program should be run as:

```
./a.out server_ip port_number filename
```

The combination of the server ip and the port number tells this program where to look for the server. The port number is fixed and it is known to me. However, I don't know how to actually connect to the server. What should I type in as the server ip? This server is located on my computer, the same one on which I am doing development of this program. For submitting this program I will be given the server_ip by my professor, but I need to test that my code works prior to doing to.

Here is the code of my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//#define SERVER_PORT "5432"
#define MAX_LINE 256

/*
 * Lookup a host IP address and connect to it using service. Arguments match the first two
 * arguments to getaddrinfo(3).
 *
 * Returns a connected socket descriptor or -1 on error. Caller is responsible for closing
 * the returned socket.
 */
int lookup_and_connect( const char *host, const char *service );


int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    char *host;
    char buf[MAX_LINE];
    int s;
    int len;
    char* server_port;
    char* file_name;

    if(argc == 4)
    {
        host = argv[1];
        server_port = argv[2];
        file_name = argv[3];
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage:\n %s server port_number filename\n", argv[0]);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }


    /* Lookup IP and connect to server */
    if ( ( s = lookup_and_connect( host, server_port ) ) < 0 ) 
    {
        // Since you can't concatenate a string literal and a char*,
        // we have to create our own error string to be passed to perror()
        char* message = "Client Error: Unable to find host ";
        size_t len1 = strlen(host);
        size_t len2 = strlen(message);
        char* error_string = (char*) malloc( len1 + len2 + 1 );
        strncpy(error_string, message, len2);
        strncpy(error_string + len2, host, len1);
        error_string[len1 + len2] = '\0';
        perror(error_string);
        free(error_string);  // deallocate the memory for the string

        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //sends file name to server
    len = strlen(file_name) + 1;
    if(send(s, file_name, len, 0 ) == -1)
    {
        perror("Client Error: send");
        close(s);
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    //get response from server
    FILE *file = NULL; 
    int num_recv;
    char *err_str  = "<error>";
    char *good_str = "<goodf>";
    const int header_len = 7;
    while (1) 
    {
        num_recv = recv(s, buf, MAX_LINE-1,0);
        if(num_recv == -1)
        {
            perror("Client Error: recv");
            close(s);
            if (file != NULL) {
                fclose(file);
            }
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        else if(num_recv== 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            /* This will only be true the first time. */
            if (file == NULL) // creates file and write once if good
            {
                if (strncmp(err_str, buf, header_len) == 0) // check error
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Server Error: file %s not found\n", file_name);
                    close(s);
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                }
                else if (strncmp(good_str, buf, header_len) == 0) // check good file
                {
                    file = fopen(file_name, "wb");
                    if (file == NULL)
                    {
                        perror("Client Error: fopen");
                        close(s);
                        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
                    }
                    fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), num_recv, file);
                }
                else  // Server sent something else.
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "Server Error: sent garbage data\n");
                    close(s);
                    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

                }
            }
            else // writes to file
            {
                fwrite(buf, sizeof(char), num_recv, file);
            }
        }

    }

    // tries to close the file
    if (fclose(file) == EOF) {
        perror("Client Error: fclose");
    }

    close( s );

    return 0;
}

int lookup_and_connect( const char *host, const char *service ) {
    struct addrinfo hints;
    struct addrinfo *rp, *result;
    int s;

    /* Translate host name into peer's IP address */
    memset( &hints, 0, sizeof( hints ) );
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    if ( ( s = getaddrinfo( host, service, &hints, &result ) ) != 0 ) {
        fprintf( stderr, "Client Error: stream-talk-client: getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror( s ) );
        return -1;
    }

    /* Iterate through the address list and try to connect */
    for ( rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next ) {
        if ( ( s = socket( rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol ) ) == -1 ) {
            continue;
        }

        if ( connect( s, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen ) != -1 ) {
            break;
        }

        close( s );
    }
    if ( rp == NULL ) {
        perror( "Client Error: stream-talk-client: connect" );
        return -1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo( result );

    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a server name of "localhost" (which always resolves to your system) or an IPv4 address of "127.0.0.1".

Comment: In the lookup_and_connect(), after calling getaddrinfo(), struct addrinfo **res == NULL, which causes the error statement to be printed. perror() prints `Connection refused`

Comment: @Galaxy That means you don't have a program running on your computer listening on that port, if I remember rightly.  (Or possibly blocked by a firewall.)

Comment: I started up the test program listening on that same port before running my C program.